# WPF UI update specifics

Tags: .net, wpf, multithreading, user-interface

**Illustration for my general question:**
Working with WPF I'm often stuck with the following problem: before firing up a UI-heavy operation I turn on a visual feedback control for showing  that the system is busy (some sort of a busy indicator); however the UI freezes without showing the busy indicator before it.

```
private void MyTree_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.MyBusyIndicator.IsBusy = true;
        ...
        //then some UI related operation
        ...
        this.MyBusyIndicator.IsBusy = false;
    }
```

(I can't move that time consuming operation to another thread, because it is the UI-thread related operation.)
Searching around for a possible solution or recommendation on solving such a problem, I read something about some WPF (or even .NET framework) UI updating specifics  which is the main cause for this type of problem.

**So my question:**
What is those WPF (or .NET framework) UI updating mechanism specifics, **which prevents UI to be updated in exactly the same sequence as it was defined in a code?**

Is it specific to WPF only indeed?

What are possible solutions or workarounds?

Is it a real problem or maybe just a result of my poor understanding?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem isn't specific to WPF - most UI frameworks behave the same way.

The problem here is that your UI won't update until the UI thread can process messages.  As long as you're doing work (the UI related operations), the UI thread is busy and can't process the messages required to redraw the screen.  In this case, that means that busy indicator won't redraw until after everything is completed.

The real solution here is to move the operations into a background thread.  While you say that all of these are UI-thread related, there's typically a way to separate out portions of this in WPF.  The key is to think about the parts that are taking a long time, and move them, and only them, out.  This typically means loading your data, but not setting it to the UI (ie: setting the bound property) until after it's completely loaded and processed.

If that's completely not possible, the only real option is to set your busy indicator, then use some mechanism to push the other work off until after the UI thread can process.  This can be done by using Dispatcher.BeginInvoke to push the remaining work off until "later", though it's somewhat hackish to do.  This would look like:

```
private void MyTree_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    this.MyBusyIndicator.IsBusy = true;

    this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke( (Action) () =>
    {
        // This is now sent to the dispatcher to process later, which gives the busy indicator a chance to refresh...

        //then some UI related operation
        this.MyBusyIndicator.IsBusy = false;
    });
}
```

That being said, this isn't always perfectly reliable, either - as you're still locking your UI thread.  Ideally, you should never block the UI, as it will prevent redraws from occurring correctly...  A DispatcherTimer would work more reliably, but again, is really not a very good way to handle it.

Comment: Thank you, Reed, for your helpful answer! +1. In practice I often use hackish approaches like those you described (and as you pointed out it is not always working reliably). But I'd like to understand the cause of the issue a little bit more clearly. Could you, please, give some more details (or, maybe, some links) on the 'process messages required to redraw the screen' you mentioned. Why the screen can not be updated before UI thread starting next piece of work? Just as our commands go: first - BusyIndicator, the next - the rest of the job. Why is it messed up subsequently?

Comment: @rem: Changing a value doesn't really change the UI - it's more like it posts a message onto the UI message pump, so the drawing occurs later.  (Otherwise, a bunch of changes would take forever...)  THink of a UI change as a request like "Change this as soon as you next update and layout".  Unfortunately, the "update and layout" happens, but not until the UI thread is idle and can process the message pump...

Comment: @Reed Copsey: Thanks! I didn't happen to work with WinForms but heard that there there is a possibility to force a UI update right at the moment you need, is it true?

Comment: @rem: WinForms can - but it's problematic.  There isn't a "good" way to do it in general...

Answer (score 0):

In .NET You can use Thread Queue

```
private void Button_Click( object sender, RoutedEventArgs e )
{
  ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(
        delegate
        {
            // GUI Thread call
            this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke( 
                    DispatcherPriority.Normal,
                    new Action( () => { this.MyBusyIndicator.IsBusy = true; }) )

            // Action in non-GUI Thread
            ... 

            // GUI Thread call
            this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke( 
                    DispatcherPriority.Normal,
                    new Action( () => { this.MyBusyIndicator.IsBusy = false; }) )
        } );
   }
}
```